# default currency being used instead of page currency on confirmation pages

Tags: civievent, currency

I administer a site with a default currency of Euros. However, they also do payments for some things in other currencies. It all seems to work fine on contribution pages with both the confirmation page and the receipt (after a Smarty tweak) showing the correct currency.

I've just set up their first event using USD and although the registration page and receipt are correct, the confirmation page shows Euros. Right amounts, but wrong currency.
Is this a known problem? I assume there is something hardcoded somewhere in this legacy part of CiviCRM.
Thoughts?

Comment: You can try the patch here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3381

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demerit's pointer revealed the solution. Probably I should create a pull request to fix the bug, but all I did for the moment was add the following line to civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php as indicated in [this bug report](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3381).

```
$this->assign('currency', $params['currencyID']);
```